# Run mocha unit-test on docker-compose images

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, mocha.js

I have an api in nodeJs, which run under micro-services.
So far it work, what i want to do next is to be able to run unit-test (mocha) on those images.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:   db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  db-seeds:
    build: ./services/mongo-seeds
    links:
      - db

  gateway:
    build: ./services/gateway
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    depends_on:
      - A
      - B
      - C

  A:
    build: ./services/A
    ports:
      - 4003:4000
    depends_on:
      - db

  B:
    build: ./services/B
    ports:
      - 4001:4000
    depends_on:
      - db

  C:
    build: ./services/C
    ports:
      - 4002:4000
    depends_on:
      - db
```

One of a DockerFile:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 4000
CMD yarn start
```

What i did so far is to make another docker-compose file which will run other docker file (DockerFile.test) :

```
FROM node:latest
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 4000
CMD yarn test
```

also tried:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 4000
CMD yarn start
RUN sleep 240
CMD yarn test
```

They both fail, at this point yarn test is launch before my gateway and servers are up. What i want to do, is to launch my servers and then run my unit-test in the images, but i'm new to docker and lack knowledge on how to implement that.

yarn test:

> "test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run mocha on the same host with your docker-compose file. This can be a docker image too (which can be started with docker-compose if you want ;)

You have to run docker-compose with your services before you run yarn test.

- Create/Use a Dockerfile with docker and docker-compose and node (for your case)
- copy your sources on it (docker-compose.yml and other relevant sources)
- run docker-compose up -d on it
- run yarn test on it

Tools like CloudFoundry or OpenStack might do this job. 
If you are with CloudFoundry I can give you concrete details.

To concatenate several commands use the unix-cli syntax:

```
RUN  docker-compose up -d && \
     service1 && \
     yarn test
```

Comment: Got it, it helped, i.e: docker-compose run service_name yarn test.
Do you know if i can chain multiple service argument i.e: docker-compose run service1 service2 service3 yarn test ?

Comment: If the answer is correct and solves the problem you can upvote it :)